# OpenBSD 6.1 not updating

Tags: openbsd

I am using Openbsd 6.1/amd64 here.

Suddenly, I am no longer able to update or install a package.

When trying to do a

```
pkg_add vlc
```

I am greeted with the message:

```
https://ftp.OpenBSD.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.1/packages-stable/amd64/: ftp: SSL write error: ocsp verify failed: ocsp response not current
https://ftp.OpenBSD.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.1/packages-stable/amd64/: ftp: SSL write error: ocsp verify failed: ocsp response not current
https://ftp.OpenBSD.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.1/packages-stable/amd64/: empty
```

I already ran `pkg_add -uU`, and `pkg_check` however, still the same errors.

Have you a suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely a temporary issue, I can reproduce it. The mirror that I'm using, `https://ftp.eu.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD`, works as expected.

[Someone reported this](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=149722567012875) to the `openbsd-misc` mailing list. [A response says](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=149726333820487):

> It's a server-side problem, same on www.openbsd.org. Not visible in
>   normal graphical browsers because they fallback to the CA's OCSP server
>   whereas `ftp(1)` just relies on the stapled cert.
>
> Simplest workaround is to use a mirror, [...]

It will likely be resolved within a day or two (my guess). In the meanwhile, use [one of the many mirror sites](https://www.openbsd.org/ftp.html).

---

UPDATE (the day after): The issue has now been resolved on the affected servers.

---

Note that `-U` is never needed when you run `pkg_add -u`. It's only when you install a new package that `-U` will update any outdated packages that the new package depends on.  With `pkg_add -u` you update all packages.

Answer (score 8):

I just wanted to add that you will get the same error message if your system time is off.  I got the same error, tried using a mirror as Kusalananda suggested but still had SSL errors.  I checked the system time, and it was about two weeks behind.  Running `ntpd -s` fixed the issue and `pkg_add` worked again.

Comment: It was not my case, however thanks for the feedback. Maybe it is useful for someone else.

Comment: To enable ntpd (sync time) edit `/etc/rc.conf`. Find line with `ntpd_flags` and replace it with `ntpd_flags="-s"`. It resolved my issue with "pkg_add" - date was 2 days behind in restored virtual machine