# How to change OpenBSD mirror

Tags: package-management, openbsd, mirror

I need to change the mirror I am using in my OpenBSD 6.1 installation according to this question: [OpenBSD 6.1 not updating](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370628/openbsd-6-1-not-updating/370634)

Right now, I am using `ftp.OpenBSD.org` and I need to change it to `ftp.eu.OpenBSD.org`.

I also have the incentive as leaving it pointing to the European mirror for good, as I am located in Europe.

How may I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change an OpenBSD installation/update mirror path in OpenBSD 6.1, you need to edit the file `/etc/installurl` that you have created at installation time.

So to change the mirror you are using, edit `/etc/installurl` and change it to:

```
https://ftp.eu.OpenBSD.org/pub/OpenBSD
```

From [`man installurl`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.1/installurl)

> The /etc/installurl file contains a single line specifying an OpenBSD
>   mirror server URL, such as https://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD It is
>   created by the installer script during installations and upgrades over
>   HTTP.

An alternate way is also setting `PKG_PATH` as in:

```
export PKG_PATH="http://ftp.eu.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/$(uname -r)/packages/$(arch -s)/"
```

Or editing `installpath` within `/etc/pkg.conf`:

```
installpath = ftp.eu.openbsd.org
```

Comment: `installurl` is pretty new, I'm not sure it's even supposed to work on 6.1 release.  The standard way to do it is to set `PKG_PATH` (rumors of its death are greatly exaggerated ;)).

Comment: @SatoKatsura I am using it in 6.1, and actually it was suggested by the installation procedure. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @SatoKatsura On OpenBSD 6.1, you _should_ use `installurl`. `PKG_PATH` (and `TRUSTED_PKG_PATH`) is for pointing to package repositories in non-standard locations (these override `installurl` for `pkg_add`). `installurl` is also used by `syspatch`, which is new in OpenBSD 6.1, and also, I believe, by the `bsd.rd` system.

Comment: `PKG_PATH` (and `TRUSTED_PKG_PATH`) is for pointing to package repositories in non-standard locations (these override `installurl` for `pkg_add`). - Which I believe is what the OP wants?

Comment: I actually changed it for good. I am located in Europe btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
# echo "export PKG_PATH=https://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/$(uname -r)/packages/$(arch -s)/" >> /etc/profile
# . /etc/profile
```

Comment: Not if it's the first thing you do on a machine! :) Updated with append operator